# Apache Ignite Docker Image apacheignite/ignite:2.13.0 has many vulnerabilities

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

All, We ran Twist lock scan for above specified image and observed many vulnerabilities, Can we get new image with fixes or is there any other way to fix vulnerabilities?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not programming related as described in [help/on-topic] (alternatively: too generic, asking for software/tool recommendation, setup-related)

Comment: I think this question should be asked on the corresponding mail list: dev@ignite.apache.org